# Why does my Expo IOS release build crash on launch? "TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found"

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I’m using React Native with Expo managed workflow w/ config plugins.

This is the error:
 `Fatal Exception: RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes`

An Android release build with `npx expo run:android --variant release` is fine, but ios build with `npx expo run:ios --configuration Release` crashes on launch. All builds succeed (EAS and otherwise), but ios crashes on startup. Someone else had the issue [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23525)

My initial thought is that the bundle configuration on ios isn't being marked as release/production, even though I'm building for it. see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26987).  To try and fix this, I tried building the jsbundle with `npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.ts --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios` (the —dev false was the issue with a lot of other people getting this error).
I also tried to change the build config in Xcode to target release but that didn’t seem to work.

I might have done the past two things wrong, but realistically, I shouldn’t be having to do this with Expo.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with `npx expo install --fix`. This updated a few packages like `expo-router` from v1 to v2 which I think did the trick.